# How to use categorial properties of Vertices and Edges to draw colors in graph-tool?

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I have a graph_tool.Graph generated as follows:

```
import random
import graph_tool.all as gt 

G = gt.Graph() 

# Add a categorical property 
cprop = G.new_vertex_property('string')
G.vertex_properties['type'] = cprop

# Add some verticies with alternating properties 
for idx in range(10):
    v = G.add_vertex()
    G.vp['type'][v] = 'even' if idx % 2 == 0 else 'odd'

# Add some edges 
for idx in range(20):
    src = random.randint(0,9)
    dst = random.randint(0,9)
    G.add_edge(G.vertex(src), G.vertex(dst))


gt.graph_draw(G, vertex_color=cprop)
```

The (fairly obvious) value error is:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "even"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "even"
could not convert string to float: even
```

I'd prefer not to have to set up custom color maps and the like and then map these property names to color, is there some easy way to map categorical values to colors (e.g. something similar to [`prop_to_size`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.prop_to_size))?

**Update**

Well, unfortunately even a simple map doesn't work. I tried something like this:

```
cmap: {"even": "#9b59b6", "odd": "#3498db"}
vcolor = G.vp['type']
vcolor.a = map(lambda c: cmap[c], vcolor.a)

gt.grapgh_draw(G, vertex_color=vcolor)
```

But the new error is:

```
ValueError: Cannot get array for value type: string
```

So even my earlier simple suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't really understand what you were trying to do. If you'd like to set RGB values to color your edges for example, you can do;

```
#Add a property map
edge_color = G.new_edge_property('vector<double>')
G.edge_properties['edge_color']=edge_color

#Color your edges
for e in G.edges():
    edge_color[e] = (r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0, alpha)
```

Where r,g,b are your RGB values, between 0.0 and 255.0 and alpha is between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: I have a property that already has categorical values in it; I'd like those categorical values (or even continuous ones) to be colored in the same way that they're sized in graph tool. I guess what you're saying is that I manually have to set every single color myself?